# Var in and outside of a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, scope

I am having the same problem as another fellow on the forums, but his solution did not work for me, so I was told to make a new thread.The problem is that the new value calc in the for-loop is not being updating the res outside. It is like the inside and outside vars are different because when I remove the last res, the first goes gray and says it was never accessed.

```
    double res = 0; // result
    for (int i = 0; i>=poly.size() - 1; i++) {

        res += poly.get(i) * var;
    }

    return res;
```

The value of res is always 0; i removed the rest of the block, so I dont get in trouble

Comment: is var 0? Have you tried just putting a constant instead of that statement after the +=?

Comment: What is the value of `var`?

Comment: The second statement in a for loop initialization specifies the condition that needs to be met for the loop to run. Obviously you're not going to meet that condition with your starting value of 0 so the loop is never run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it always returns 0 because the loop doesn't run given your condition is likely false and when it's not it's useless (as a loop) anyways.

You use this code - `for (int i = 0; i>=poly.size() - 1; i++)` - which initializes `i` to 0 and then is checked against the size of the array with the expectation it will be `>=`. But that will only happen when `size()` is 1 or 0.

What you need is `for (int i = 0; i < poly.size(); i++)`.

Answer (score 0):

Change >= to <= and it will work based on the given information. The reason being is the code you provided will either be an eternal loop, or the for loop will never run as 0 is not greater than poly.size(). Seeing as you're getting output, then it is the latter that is the issue.

```
double res = 0; // result
for (int i = 0; i<=poly.size() - 1; i++) {

    res += poly.get(i) * var;
}

return res;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible chances that make it wrong:

**First** The `var` variable is 0

**Second** Your condition is wrong, you have to make sure that your condition is what you need, otherwise it will always return false

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < poly.size() ; i++) {
```

Or

```
for (int i = 0; i <= poly.size() - 1 ; i++) {
```

And make sure var != 0

Answer (score -2):

Do this:

```
double res = 0; // result
System.out.println("poly size: " + poly.size());
for (int i = 0; i>=poly.size() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println("res before: " + res);
    res += poly.get(i) * var;
    System.out.println("res after: " + res);
}

return res;
```

And I'm sure you'll realize what's going on

Comment: "And I'm sure you're realize what's going on" is not an answer.